# Showing a queueing system is a Markov Chain

Tags: markov-chains, queueing-theory, birth-death-process

I generally understand how to do this but I'm having trouble with a formal proof.

"Consider an $M/M/1/m+1$ queue with exponential arrivals rate $\lambda$, exponential service rate $\mu$, and finite waiting room capacity $m$.

Let $X_{n}$ be the number of customers in the system just after the $n$th departure. Show that $\{X_n; \: n \geq 0\}$ is a Markov Chain with state space $E = \{0,...,m\}$ and derive it's transition matrix $P$.

I understand the definition of a Markov Chain says that $$P\{X_n = x_{n} | X_{n-1} = x_{n-1}, .... X_{0} = x_{0}\} = P\{X_{n} = x_{n} | X_{n-1} = x_{n-1}\}$$ or that given the present, the future is independent of the past.

How can that be shown for this particular queue though? As far as showing the state space $E = \{0,...,m\}$ I can reason it out that there are only $m$ states that this chain can be in since there are only $m$ spots in the waiting room and therefore anyone else must leave, but again not sure how to formally prove it.

My thoughts are that since this is a birth-death process, the system can only increase by one, decrease by one, or remain the same. And the transition matrix would have rows with

$\mu_{i} - (\lambda_{i}+\mu_{i})  \lambda_i$ (besides the first and last rows)

Is this the correct way to proceed, or is this a different scenario since we are considering the number of customers in the system "just after the $n$th departure."

Comment: In order to show that the Markov property holds, one could just write down explicitly the two probabilities $P(X_n=x_n ~|~ X_{n-1}=x_{n-1}, \dots, X-0=x_0)$ and $P(X_n=x_n ~|~ X_{n-1}=x_{n-1})$ and show that they are equal. The key idea is to use the memoryless properties of the exponential distribution. Indeed the time between two departure as well as the time between two arrival are exponentially distributed.

Comment: @alezok right, thanks! Is there any way to show the state space other then intuition? And would my matrix be correct or is that only showing the number of customers in the system and not "just after the nth departure"?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "show the state space"? Your Markov chain $X_n$ is precisely describing the queueing system after the $n$-th departure. Indeed this Markov chain can jump from state $k$ to any state $k+l$ (provided that there have been $l+1$ customer arrivals between two departures). In view of this, it is not a birth-death process. In order to describe the actual number of customer in the system at any time instant one must use a continuous time Markov process, which is an actual birth-death process.

Answer (score 1):

Given the state space $E=\{0,\ldots,m\}$ we need to find the transition probabilities and prove the Markov property.

For any state $i\geq 1$, consider how we can get to any other state $j$ in one step. If $j <= i-2$ then it's obviously impossible because with the first departure the step is complete.

Next, if $j=i-1$ then transition occurs if the next system event is a departure. And generally, for $i-1\leq j\leq m-1$, transition to $j$ occurs if the next $j-i+1$ events are arrivals followed by a departure, and this occurs with probability $\;\left(\dfrac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}\right)^{j-i+1}\dfrac{\mu}{\lambda+\mu}$.

If $j=m$, transition occurs if the next $m-i+1$ events are arrivals. Any further arrivals before the next departure are ignored (the waiting room is full). Thus, the probability of this transition is $\;\left(\dfrac{\lambda}{\lambda+\mu}\right)^{m-i+1}$.

For state $i=0$, the first system event can only be an arrival, giving us the same situation as when $i=1$. So the transition probabilities for $i=0$ are the same as for $i=1$.

For the Markov property, there is almost nothing to prove. The above transition probabilities depend only on the current state $i$ and not any previous state because of the assumed independence of the customer arrival and departure waiting times.

The transition probability matrix is, letting $\gamma = \lambda+\mu$:

$$
    P=  \begin{bmatrix}
        \dfrac{\mu}{\gamma} & \dfrac{\lambda\mu}{\gamma^2} & \dfrac{\lambda^2\mu}{\gamma^3} & \dfrac{\lambda^3\mu}{\gamma^4} & \cdots & \dfrac{\lambda^{m}}{\gamma^{m}} \\
        \dfrac{\mu}{\gamma} & \dfrac{\lambda\mu}{\gamma^2} & \dfrac{\lambda^2\mu}{\gamma^3} & \dfrac{\lambda^3\mu}{\gamma^4} & \cdots & \dfrac{\lambda^{m}}{\gamma^{m}} \\
        0 & \dfrac{\mu}{\gamma} & \dfrac{\lambda\mu}{\gamma^2} & \dfrac{\lambda^2\mu}{\gamma^3} & \cdots & \dfrac{\lambda^{m-1}}{\gamma^{m-1}} \\
        0 & 0 & \dfrac{\mu}{\gamma} & \dfrac{\lambda\mu}{\gamma^2} & \cdots & \dfrac{\lambda^{m-2}}{\gamma^{m-2}} \\
        & \cdots \\
        0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \dfrac{\mu}{\gamma} & \dfrac{\lambda}{\gamma} \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: I understand that for i=0, the only possible event is an arrival. Why is this the same case for i=1?

Comment: @Susan I don't mean for $i=1$ the only possible event is an arrival. This is only for $i=0$. But once that arrival happens we then have one customer in the system, which is the same situation as when we transition into state $1$.